# If $R$ is a ring, what does $R^2$ mean in the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, chinese-remainder-theorem

In ring theory, the Chinese Remainder Theorem is stated as follows.

Let $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ be ideals in a ring $R$ such that $R^2 + A_i = R$ for all $i$ and $A_i + A_j = R$ for all $i \neq j$. If $b_1, \dotsc, b_n \in R$, then there exists $b \in R$ such that
$$b \equiv b_i \pmod{A_i}$$
where $i = 1,\dotsc, n$. Furthermore $b$ is uniquely determined up to congruence modulo the ideal $A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n$.

As mentioned in the title, what is $R^2?$ At first, I thought it was the Cartesian product of $R$, but after reading the proof of the above theorem, that's definitely not it.

Thanks!

**Edit** The way the theorem is written above is taken from Thomas Hungerford's book "Algebra"

Comment: I've never seen such a formulation. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Bernard I got it from Thomas Hungerford's book called Algebra.

Comment: It is defined in the book.

Comment: @Randall I definitely missed it then. I'll have another look

Comment: In my copy it's on page 124, right before Theorem 2.6

Comment: @Randall Mind posting the image as an answer? Or a transcription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source you reference, the author takes non-empty subsets $A, B$ of a ring $R$ and defines the subset $AB$ to be the set of all finite sums
$$
a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \cdots +a_kb_k
$$
where $a_i \in A, b_i \in B$.  He then declares that $A^n$ will be shorthand for this construction applied to $A$ $n$ times in succession.

He then proves that when $A$ and $B$ are ideals in $R$, so is $AB$.

In particular $R^2$ is then the ideal $RR$ consisting of all finite sums of the form
$$
a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \cdots +a_kb_k
$$
where $a_i , b_i \in R$.

*Source*:  fifth printing of *Algebra* by Thomas W. Hungerford, Springer-Verlag 1989.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).